# Rotate image in python and remove the background

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

[image]

Is there a way to rotate these kind of images and remove the background whitespace or any background and get and image like this

[image]

I tried to remove the background if the image doesn't have any rotation  i am able to remove the background whitespace by using this script but if the image got any rotation it doesn't remove any space
i followed this [How to crop or remove white background from an image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48395434/how-to-crop-or-remove-white-background-from-an-image)

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

img = cv2.imread('cheque_img\rotate.PNG')
## (1) Convert to gray, and threshold
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
th, threshed = cv2.threshold(gray, 240, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)

## (2) Morph-op to remove noise
kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_ELLIPSE, (11,11))
morphed = cv2.morphologyEx(threshed, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, kernel)

## (3) Find the max-area contour
cnts = cv2.findContours(morphed, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)[-2]
cnt = sorted(cnts, key=cv2.contourArea)[-1]

## (4) Crop and save it
x,y,w,h = cv2.boundingRect(cnt)
dst = img[y:y+h, x:x+w]
cv2.imwrite("001.png", dst)
```

Please try it with any scanned image and rotate it and try to get rid of the background white space and rotate it to its original dimension for doing computer vision operation

Comment: Try using Perspective Transform. Link to documentation: https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_geometric_transformations/py_geometric_transformations.html

Comment: @VardanAgarwal The problem is , the co-ordinates of the image might be different for different picture,

Comment: I guess that the question you should ask is "how can I find the coordinates of the corners of the documents". The rest is easy work.

Comment: @YvesDaoust How can i find the coordinates of the dynamic images , yes true!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering you don't know the angle of the rotation and can be different for each scanned image, you need to find it first.

Combine what you already did with accepted answer for [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46731947/detect-angle-and-rotate-an-image-in-python/46732132) question.

For the image you provided:

```
Angle is -25.953375702364195
```

[image]

Comment: It does rotate the image but doesn't remove the white space using the above code.Thank you for part 1 solution

Answer (score 4):

Using *cv2.boundingRect* will give you the minimum non-rotating rectangle that fit the contour. *cv2.boundingRect* result :

[image]

Instead of *cv2.boundingRect*, you will need to use *cv2.minAreaRect* to obtain a rectangle that fit the contour. *cv2.minAreaRect* result :

[image]

After the obtaining the rotated rect information, you will need to find the affine transform matrix between the model points and the current points. Current points are the points found in rotated rect and the model point is the point of the original object. In this case an object with the initial location (0,0) and the width and height of the rotated rect.

Affine might be an overkill here but for generality affine transform is used.

[image]

Detailed explanation is located in the code.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

img = cv2.imread('Bcm3h.png')

## (1) Convert to gray, and threshold
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
th, threshed = cv2.threshold(gray, 240, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)


## (2) Morph-op to remove noise
kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_ELLIPSE, (11,11))
morphed = cv2.morphologyEx(threshed, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, kernel)

## (3) Find the max-area contour
cnts = cv2.findContours(morphed, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)[-2]
cnt = sorted(cnts, key=cv2.contourArea)[-1]


## This will extract the rotated rect from the contour
rot_rect = cv2.minAreaRect(cnt)

# Extract useful data
cx,cy = (rot_rect[0][0], rot_rect[0][1]) # rect center
sx,sy = (rot_rect[1][0], rot_rect[1][1]) # rect size
angle = rot_rect[2] # rect angle


# Set model points : The original shape
model_pts = np.array([[0,sy],[0,0],[sx,0],[sx,sy]]).astype('int')
# Set detected points : Points on the image
current_pts = cv2.boxPoints(rot_rect).astype('int')

# sort the points to ensure match between model points and current points
ind_model = np.lexsort((model_pts[:,1],model_pts[:,0]))
ind_current = np.lexsort((current_pts[:,1],current_pts[:,0]))

model_pts = np.array([model_pts[i] for i in ind_model])
current_pts = np.array([current_pts[i] for i in ind_current])


# Estimate the transform betwee points
M = cv2.estimateRigidTransform(current_pts,model_pts,True)

# Wrap the image
wrap_gray = cv2.warpAffine(gray, M, (int(sx),int(sy)))


# for display
cv2.imshow("dst",wrap_gray)
cv2.waitKey(0)

#cv2.imwrite("001.png", dst)
```

Result :

[image]

Comment: I am getting this error and i am using open-cv > 4.0
` wrap_gray = cv2.warpAffine(gray, M, (int(sx),int(sy)))
TypeError: Expected Ptr<cv::UMat> for argument '%s' `

Comment: can you try typecasting with cv2.umat() on the gray variable? i.e. wrap_gray = cv2.warpAffine(cv2.umat(gray), M, (int(sx),int(sy)))

Comment: I tried that as well as tried this
img = cv2.UMat(cv2.imread("image.jpg", cv2.IMREAD_COLOR))
imgUMat = cv2.UMat(img)
gray = cv2.cvtColor(imgUMat, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY) 

also this
gray = cv2.cvtColor(cv2.umat(img), cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

Comment: you get the same error even with the modifications?

Comment: Yes i do, i guess it has to do something with the warpAffine function, because with the same code excluding the warpAffine i can get a image response.

Comment: Could you please check your opencv version and if it is less than 4.0 could you please create another environment and update the opencv version and see what changes needs in the code. I am absolutely new in opencv image processing.

Comment: my version is lower than 4 and i have no intention of upgrading it for this problem. Maybe you can print the inputs you insert to warpaffine function and see if they are proper

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/205487/discussion-between-datadoctor-and-yapws87).

Comment: Check your version of cv2.findContours to see how many items are returned. Different versions of OpenCV return different number of items and the actual contours may be at a different position in the returned items.

Answer (score 0):

If the background is guaranteed to be saturated white (value 255) and the document mostly unsaturated values, binarize below the threshold 255 and fit a bounding rectangle.

Comment: Please share some documentation where can i do that ,thank you

Comment: @DataDoctor: OpenCV.

Answer (score 0):

I had some problems running the code presented above, so here is my slightly modified version:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

def crop_minAreaRect(img, rect):
    # rotate img
    angle = rect[2]
    print("angle: " + str(angle))
    rows,cols = img.shape[0], img.shape[1]
      
    M = cv2.getRotationMatrix2D((cols/2,rows/2),angle,1)
    img_rot = cv2.warpAffine(img,M,(cols,rows))

    # rotate bounding box
    rect0 = (rect[0], rect[1], angle) 
    box = cv2.boxPoints(rect0)
    pts = np.int0(cv2.transform(np.array([box]), M))[0]    
    pts[pts < 0] = 0

    # crop
    img_crop = img_rot[pts[1][1]:pts[0][1], 
                       pts[1][0]:pts[2][0]]

    return img_crop
    
def ResizeWithAspectRatio(image, width=None, height=None, inter=cv2.INTER_AREA):
    dim = None
    (h, w) = image.shape[:2]

    if width is None and height is None:
        return image
    if width is None:
        r = height / float(h)
        dim = (int(w * r), height)
    else:
        r = width / float(w)
        dim = (width, int(h * r))

    return cv2.resize(image, dim, interpolation=inter)

img = cv2.imread('rotatedCheque.png')
cv2.imshow("orig", img)
img_copy = img.copy()

# (1) Convert to gray, and threshold
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
th, threshed = cv2.threshold(gray, 240, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)

# (2) Morph-op to remove noise
kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_ELLIPSE, (11, 11))
morphed = cv2.morphologyEx(threshed, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, kernel)

# (3) Find the max-area contour
cnts = cv2.findContours(morphed, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)[-2]
cnt = sorted(cnts, key=cv2.contourArea)[-1]

# This will extract the rotated rect from the contour
rot_rect = cv2.minAreaRect(cnt)

cropped_img = crop_minAreaRect(img, rot_rect)

width, height = img.shape[0], img.shape[1]
if height > width:
  cropped_img = cv2.rotate(cropped_img, cv2.ROTATE_90_CLOCKWISE)
  
resized_img = ResizeWithAspectRatio(cropped_img, width=800)

cv2.imshow("cropped", resized_img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```