# Correct the object orientation in the image. Calculate the correct angle of rotation and correct the alignment of the object in the image

Tags: python, opencv, deep-learning, computer-vision

I have cropped images of electronic meter reading. Those readings are taken in random style. I need the orientation of the object(not the image) in the image to be aligned.
[image]

1. The detection of contours is not working. As there are lots of contours are formed in the image and in order to calculate the angle I need to select the right contour. Some times contour is not formed.

2.I want set of rotated images as shown in figure above. I tried some code of rotating image from the OpenCV. But due to two type of use case ( as we don't know from code that the reading style may be any of the two) The images are turned out as below.
[image]

4. Using the code below I am able to find the angle of rotation but for any one case. I need it to be done automatically for both type of cases. Also see the data set I have attached for other type of examples.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np


debug = True

# Display image
def display(img, frameName="OpenCV Image"):
    if not debug:
        return
    h, w = img.shape[0:2]
    neww = 800
    newh = int(neww*(h/w))
    img = cv2.resize(img, (neww, newh))
    plt.imshow(img)
    plt.show()
#     cv2.imshow(frameName, img)
#     cv2.waitKey(0)

#rotate the image with given theta value
def rotate(img, theta):
    rows, cols = img.shape[0], img.shape[1]
    image_center = (cols/2, rows/2)
    
    M = cv2.getRotationMatrix2D(image_center,theta,1)

    abs_cos = abs(M[0,0])
    abs_sin = abs(M[0,1])

    bound_w = int(rows * abs_sin + cols * abs_cos)
    bound_h = int(rows * abs_cos + cols * abs_sin)

    M[0, 2] += bound_w/2 - image_center[0]
    M[1, 2] += bound_h/2 - image_center[1]

    # rotate orignal image to show transformation
    rotated = cv2.warpAffine(img,M,(bound_w,bound_h),borderValue=(255,255,255))
    return rotated


def slope(x1, y1, x2, y2):
    if x1 == x2:
        return 0
    slope = (y2-y1)/(x2-x1)
    theta = np.rad2deg(np.arctan(slope))
    return theta


def main(filePath):
    img = cv2.imread(filePath)
    (hi, wi) = img.shape[:2]
    textImg = img.copy()

    small = cv2.cvtColor(textImg, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

    # find the gradient map
    kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_ELLIPSE, (3, 3))
    grad = cv2.morphologyEx(small, cv2.MORPH_GRADIENT, kernel)

    display(grad)

    # Binarize the gradient image
    _, bw = cv2.threshold(grad, 0.0, 255.0, cv2.THRESH_BINARY | cv2.THRESH_OTSU)
    display(bw)

    # connect horizontally oriented regions
    # kernal value (9,1) can be changed to improved the text detection
    kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (9, 1))
    connected = cv2.morphologyEx(bw, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, kernel)
    display(connected)

    # using RETR_EXTERNAL instead of RETR_CCOMP
    # _ , contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(connected.copy(), cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)
    contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(connected.copy(), cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE) #opencv >= 4.0



    mask = np.zeros(bw.shape, dtype=np.uint8)
    display(mask)
    # cumulative theta value
    cummTheta = 0
    # number of detected text regions
    ct = 0
    flag=False
    for idx in range(len(contours)):
        x, y, w, h = cv2.boundingRect(contours[idx])
        mask[y:y+h, x:x+w] = 0
        # fill the contour
        cv2.drawContours(mask, contours, idx, (255, 255, 255), -1)
        display(mask)
        # ratio of non-zero pixels in the filled region
        r = float(cv2.countNonZero(mask[y:y+h, x:x+w])) / (w * h)

        # assume at least 45% of the area is filled if it contains text
        # if r > 0.39 and w > 8 and h > 8:
        if (h/hi)>0.4 and (w/wi)>0.4:
            flag=True
            print(r,w,h)
            # cv2.rectangle(textImg, (x1, y), (x+w-1, y+h-1), (0, 255, 0), 2)

            rect = cv2.minAreaRect(contours[idx])
            box = cv2.boxPoints(rect)
            box = np.int0(box)
            cv2.drawContours(textImg,[box],0,(0,0,255),2)
            
            center = (int(rect[0][0]),int(rect[0][1]))
            width = int(rect[1][0])
            height = int(rect[1][1])
            angle = int(rect[2])
            print(angle)
            print(width,height)


            if width < height:
                angle = 90+angle
            print(angle,'final')

            # we can filter theta as outlier based on other theta values
            # this will help in excluding the rare text region with different orientation from ususla value 
            theta = slope(box[0][0], box[0][1], box[1][0], box[1][1])
            cummTheta += theta
            ct +=1 
            # print("Theta", theta)
            
            # find the average of all cumulative theta value
            # orientation = cummTheta/ct
            print("Image orientation in degress: ", angle)
            finalImage = rotate(img, angle)
            display(textImg, "Detectd Text minimum bounding box")
            display(finalImage)
            out_path='cropped_corrected/rotated/'+filePath.split('\\')[-1]
            
            print(out_path)
            cv2.imwrite(out_path,finalImage)
            print('image svaed here in rotated')
            break
    if not flag:
        out_path='cropped_corrected/not_rotated/'+filePath.split('\\')[-1]
        print(out_path)
        cv2.imwrite(out_path,img)
        print('image svaed here without rotated')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    filePath = 'cropped/N3963001963.jpg'
    main(filePath)
```

I am attaching some sample images that need to be rotated and the object inside the image needs to be aligned:

[image] [image] [image] [image] [image] [image]